# UK ISA once invested can it be spilt but kept in ISA state

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

In the UK ISAs are protected from tax, both income and capital gains, and they can be transferred between investments.

During the current tax year (2017/8) investments are capped at 20k a year.

A prudent choice would be to diversify these investments, however I don't know if there is a way to split an ISA transfer between different investments once made.

I'm asking because say I have a cash ISA with 40k. But wish to invest it now in two IFISA with peer to peer lenders to diversify the risk, one investing in business and the other in personal loans?

Comment: What did your ISA provider say when you asked them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For ISA contributions made this tax year, you can only transfer the entire contribution (I think this is so just one provider can keep track that you haven't gone over the limit).

For contributions made in past tax years, you can transfer just some of them if you want, so you should be able to make one transfer to the first receiver and then a second transfer of the remaining balance to the other.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts/transferring-your-isa